# Convex optimization issues

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I have to optimize a function $f(a,b,c_{ij})$ which consists of a terms like matrix
$\mathrm{X = A + B + C}$ where $\mathrm{A}$ is a diagonal matrix with the diagonal elements equal to $a$. $\mathrm{B}$ is another diagonal matrix with the diagonal elements equal to $b$.  $\mathrm{C}$ is matrix with elements $c_{ij}$. Also the function consists of terms like $ga + hb$ where $g$ and $h$ are constants, I mean the linear terms wrt $a$ and $b$ variables. Now I have the gradient of the function wrt variables $a,b,c_{ij}$. However, I want to update such that the function is maximized and also the matrix $\mathrm{X}$ is positive definite.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Is your "positive definite" matrix $X$ also supposed to be symmetric, i.e. is $C$ restricted to be symmetric?

Comment: In what way does $X$ appear in your objective function?

Comment: @Well I have a logdet(X) term and X*l terms where l is a  linear function in a and b, while X is a matrix with a,b and cij variables